# How to move UIViews in a controller using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm updating an app to iOS7/8, and applying autolayout features.
In my `UIViewController` I have a few `UIViews` whose position should be modified as a `UIScrollView` updates its `contentOffset`.

When I update the `UIView's` frame (old way), I get some glitches and errors because of the controller autolayout constraints (I am using VFL for setting constraints programatically, I don't have a storyboard).

So the question is: which is the right/best way to move `UIViews` in a controller that implements Autolayout?
Maybe updating constraints? Should I use Core Animation to make any `UIView` move?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the constraints set-up in the storyboard you can set an outlet for whatever constraint you need to update (just like you do for any view).
Once you do that, you can update the constraint constant property as you need.

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
topConstraint.constant += 200;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

In the code above i am updating the topConstraint for a view and animating the changes. You need to call `[self layoutIfNeeded];` once before the constraint is modified, and again in the animation block.

Comment: What should I do if I am using Visual Format Language to setup constraints? (I have no storyboard).

Comment: It's a bit tougher with VFL, you should try using `+ constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:` for the constraint that needs updating.

Comment: `+ constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` returns an array of constraints, and you'd have to loop through that to find the one you need and then save it, which is not a very good idea

Comment: If I don't want to use animations, should I use this?:
`[self layoutIfNeeded];
topConstraint.constant += 200;
[self layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: You should't need the first one if you want to skip the animations. You can only do: `topConstraint.constant += 200; [self layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: Actually, you don't need to call `[self layoutIfNeeded]` at all if you don't need animations. It will be called by the UIKit run loop at a later time, and the screen will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

```
self.yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

And then just change the frame:

```
CGRect rect = self.yourView.frame;
// move or change size
rect.origin.x = whatever...
self.yourView.frame = rect.
```